# Create pfx-certificate

Tags: ssh, putty, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to create a pfx-certificate from my *Let's encrypt* certificate. 
I'm using PuTTY to access ssh and using this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -out mattesnille.pfx -inkey ~/ssl/keys/keyname.key -in ~/ssl/certs/certificatenamn.crt
```

I get the following message:

> 140372845418384:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1220:140372845418384:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec

Can anyone explain to an absolute beginner what this means?

It creates a pfx-certificate with 0 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to tell `openssl pkcs12` that you want to export a PKCS#12 (or PFX) file.  Do this by adding the `-export` option:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ~/ssl/keys/keyname.key -in ~/ssl/certs/certificatenamn.crt -out mattesnille.pfx
```

Without this, it expects the `-in` file to be a PKCS#12, which yours isn't.